# Is there a way to increase the screen saturation on Ubuntu?

Tags: screen, 16.10

I've searched everywhere to find a way to INCREASE screen saturation, but I found nothing ...
Has somebody an Idea?  Something like `xgamma` but for the saturation ?
I got used so much to high saturation that I feel colorblind without it...
(Don't say me CompizConfig)

Comment: What's wrong with CompizConfig in this case?

Comment: The fact that it can only DECREASE ...

Comment: do you realy need to do this in the os?most monitors have a lot of settings you can adjust including saturation.

Answer (score 0):

You should begin by accessing System Settings > Color, so you could calibrate your monitors at there. It may be necessary to install some packages, Ubuntu automatically will install them.

Comment: The option to calibrate is "unclickable" (not english btw)

Comment: Sure, calibration is disabled for me, too. According to instructions from system settings, whe could apply some predefined profiles. In my TV, blue test profile worked.

Answer (score 0):

I find it very powerful to use the graphic card's driver settings. For example, for Nvidia graphic cards, go to NVIDIA X Server Settings (make sure your have installed the correct driver if you cannot find it). Click GPU 0-(Your GPU model)->HDMI-0-(Your monitor model connected to that graphic card). The saturation can be adjusted by sliding the value of Digital Vibrance in Controls. The brightness and the contrast can be adjusted in Color Correction.